# mutt: rendering html emails using w3m

Tags: mutt, html

I occasionally receive html messages and I would like to see whether text has been formatted or colored by the sender. I can simply navigate to the attachment list and open the text/html MIME type attachment with a web browser; however, for the sake of simplicity, I would prefer for the html to be rendered as formatted text within the pager. To do this, I have enabled html rendering by `w3m` with the following line in my `.muttrc` file:

`auto_view text/html`.

Additionally, I have added to my config file lines such as the following to highlight text that the sender may have designated as important:

`color bold brightred default`.

I expect that any text that was formatted as bold by the sender will appear as `brightred` in the pager. However, this formatting is not actually applied. Instead, I see only plaintext preceded by the statement:

`[-- Autoview using /usr/bin/w3m -I 'ISO-8859-1' -dump -T text/html ''/tmp/mutt.html'' --]`.

What am I doing wrong? How do I enable display of html-formatted messages within pager?

Comment: The in-`mutt` color settings are for the built-in pager only - `mutt` has no control over `w3m` colors.  You'll have to find a way to configure `w3m` to display colors the way you want in addition to `mutt`.

Comment: @jw013: Even if I remove the w3m invocation (`auto_view text/html`), the bold text from an html email is not formatted `brightred` (as per my example). Instead, the bold text is flanked by asterisks. What do I need to do to enable coloring for the built-in pager. Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK, Mutt doesn't have the ability to render HTML.  I'm not sure where the asterisks you are seeing come from, but I don't think it's related to the color setting of the built-in pager.

Comment: @jw013: I suppose I misunderstood the `color object foreground background` syntax from [§3.9](http://www.mutt.org/doc/devel/manual.html#color) of the `mutt` documentation. I interpreted `bold` objects/patterns as being html-defined, but I now suppose these are defined as `bold` in some other manner (how?). Many thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure either but it might be as simple as plain text surrounded by asterisks.  Send yourself a *plain text* email containing a `*few* *test words*` surrounded by asterisks and see if they are displayed according to your color setting.

Comment: @jw013: Good idea. I tried, but the text appeared as I typed it. Asterisks were not replaced by colors.

Comment: Just did some testing: bold works with the (letter, `^H`, letter) sequence described in section [5.2](http://www.mutt.org/doc/devel/manual.html#pager-menu).

Comment: @jw013: Good find. That is a rather ancient and cumbersome method of bolding/underlining text. I confirmed your findings with this test message: "testing n `^H` nr `^H` ro `^H` of `^H` ff `^H` f sequence". Not only is it cumbersome to write, but it cannot be copied/pasted because the control character `^H` is converted to the sequence of two plaintext characters ^H upon pasting. Apparently, this is the method used to format `man` pages.

Comment: Ugh, I thought perhaps a solution was to make `w3m`display colours, as per the first comment. However, `mutt` [apparently](https://superuser.com/questions/929122/mutt-using-elinks-to-color-html-and-external-pager-dilemma) "overwrites the color codes coming from the external tool", so this wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Mutt does not parse HTML. If you turn off HTML viewing, you won't see HTML content. Many mailers generate [MIME multipart messages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Multipart_messages), with the same text present twice: once as an HTML part (`text/html`), and once as a text part (`text/plain`). The text part is mostly or completely devoid of formatting; some mail programs generate ASCII representations of emphasis *like* *this*.

The `bold` color setting is used by Mutt's built-in parser for [`text/enriched`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1563). Few programs send `text/enriched` content,
so you're probably seeing a plain text part, with no formatting.

If you turn on automatic HTML viewing, then mutt isn't doing the displaying. W3m handles the formatting, and it always displays bold as bold.